# PHP how to multiple rows of form via checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms

My current form includes many rows (100s) each with several values the user can choose and they click submit for each. I would like instead to give them the option to submit multiple rows at a time by using a checkbox with one submit button.

My current code is:

```
<tr>
    <form id='form$y' action=".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])." method='post''/>
    <input type='hidden' form='form$y' name='id' value='$id' />
    <td>
        <input style='height:18px' form='form$y' type='date' name='date value='$date'/>                                                                                                     
    </td>
    <td>    
        <select name='status' form='form$y' required/>
          <option>$status</option>
          <option value='option1'>option1</option>
          <option value='option2'>option2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input form='form$y' type='text' name='comment' value='$comment'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  type='submit' value='Save' />
        </form> 
    </td>               
</tr>";
```

As you can see, each row is its own form. I imagine I should be using only one total form if I'm employing check-boxes instead of individual submits? Where do I go from here? Where doe the `submit` button belong?

I suppose I should replace the `submit` column with something like this:

```
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='value$y'>
</td>
```

I'd appreciate if someone can give me an example (based on my code) of how this should work. I did read what is already there on SO but I couldn't quite get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one form -

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$id' />
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='value$y'></td>
    <td>
        <input style='height:18px' ftype='date' name='date[]' value='$date'/>                                                                                                     
    </td>
    <td>    
        <select name='status[]' required/>
          <option>$status</option>
          <option value='option1'>option1</option>
          <option value='option2'>option2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' name='comment[]' value='$comment'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>.......</tr>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
   if(count($_POST['check_list']) > 0 && !empty($_POST['check_list'][0])) {
       foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $checked) {
          $id = $_POST['id'][$key];
          // rest of the data and processings
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work except for one problem. I have the `required` validation on the fields and because it's all one form its requiring info for every row. Previously, because each row was its own form with its own submit button the validation was only required if entering in data for that row.

Comment: You have to modify the validation in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Submit Button with the form

In PHP

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
   // $_POST[check_list] will be an array with selected values only. 
   // Do whatever you want do with the $_POST[check_list] array. 
}
```